# Contact info collection from different website using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I grab a table with company's name and registration number from a website. Problem in this table is, it does not contain address of respected company. Now my job is using company name i have to collect address from there web site. I have 100 company name. It not possible to do it manually for each company. So i have find a way so it does automatically. here is my code. But it does not bring the result what I ask for.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests
from googlesearch import search
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import re 
companylist = ['ARTA Management für das Handwerk GmbH + Co.',   "aktive 
Stuttgarter", 'ABEX Dachdecker Handwerks-GmbH',
'Academie für Kunst und Handwerk e.V.', 'AHA Agentur fürs Handwerk GmbH']

for com in companylist:
    url_list = []
for url in search(com, tld='de', lang='de', stop=5):
    url_list.append(url)
webSite = requests.get(url_list[0]+'kontakt')
if webSite.status_code == 200:
    soup = BS(webSite.content, 'html.parser')
    string = ''
    for line in soup.findAll('p'):
        string = string + line.text + ' '
    match = re.search(r'\s\w+\s\Straße\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s', string)
    print(match.group())
else:
    url_list = []
    for url in search(com, tld='de', lang='de', stop=5):
        url_list.append(url)
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        if (link.get('href').endswith('kontakt/')):
            webSite = requests.get((link.get('href')))
    if webSite.status_code == 200:
        soup = BS(webSite.content, 'html.parser')
        string = ''
        for line in soup.findAll('p'):
            string = string + line.text + ' '

        match = re.search(r'\s\w+\s\Straße\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s', string)
```

Small description of the code. first i put the company name on google search and it bring back 5 links. I use the first link and go to the home page and find contact link. Then I go to contact page and grab all the text and from there I try to find company address using 're'. It not working as it should be. Please give me some suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what your expected result is, and what you are getting instead?

Comment: What do you get as output instead of what you expect?

Comment: if the company name is "AHA Agentur fürs Handwerk GmbH", then I want the output is:                                                                                                            AHA Agentur fürs Handwerk GmbH 
Ulmer Str. 27/1 (bei Oberer Haldenweg!) 
73207 Plochingen bei Stuttgart

Comment: @RussellB Honestly speaking I just got one output, for "ARTA Management für das Handwerk Gmbh + Co." company output: Eglosheimer 'Straße 40 71636 Ludwigsburg'. Rest does not bring nothing. May be code not correct.

Comment: I can't test your code right now but from just looking at it, it seems like your RegEx only finds results containing 'Straße'. In your example above (_AHA Agentur fürs Handwerk GmbH Ulmer Str. 27/1 (bei Oberer Haldenweg!) 73207 Plochingen bei Stuttgart_) there is no "Straße" so there would be no match. You might want to try to search for "Straße", "Weg", "Gasse" and "Str." instead or altogether switch to an expression based on the zip code, if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to work out some bits, as the address isn't found for all the websites. But I got it looping through. Also some of the requests are getting 404 response.

I worked it around a bit to have it retry the different search results. Maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but maybe gives you something to work with. I guess at the very least, you can find multiple addresses, and maybe leaves just a handful you'd need to go back and find manually:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests
from googlesearch import search 
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import re 


companylist = ['ARTA Management für das Handwerk GmbH + Co.',   "aktive Stuttgarter", 'ABEX Dachdecker Handwerks-GmbH',
'Academie für Kunst und Handwerk e.V.', 'AHA Agentur fürs Handwerk GmbH']

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36'}

not_found = []

for com in companylist:
    url_list = []
    for url in search(com, tld='de', lang='de', stop=50):
        url_list.append(url)
    found_contact = False


    for url2 in url_list:
        next_url = False
        while found_contact == False and next_url == False:
            try:
                webSite = requests.get(url2+'kontakt', headers=headers)
                if webSite.status_code == 200:
                    soup = BS(webSite.content, 'html.parser')
                    string = ''
                    for line in soup.findAll('p'):
                        string = string + line.text + ' '
                    match = re.search(r'\s\w+\s\Straße\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s', string)
                    try:
                        print('Found: %s\n%s' %(com,match.group().strip()),'\n')
                        found_contact = True
                        next_url = True
                        if com in not_found:
                            del not_found[com]
                        continue
                    except:
                        print('Attempt: %s of %s: Address not found for: %s' %(url_list.index(url2)+1, len(url_list),com))
                        next_url = True
                        if com not in not_found:
                            not_found.append(com)
                else:
                    next_url = True
                    print('Attempt: %s of %s: Address not found for: %s' %(url_list.index(url2)+1, len(url_list),com))
            except:
                next_url = True
                print('Attempt: %s of %s: Address not found for: %s' %(url_list.index(url2)+1, len(url_list),com))
```

**Additioanl:**

Not the quickest way, but you could use Selenium to automote looking up these companies.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

url = 'https://www.firmenwissen.de/index.html'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36'}

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

companylist = ['ARTA Management für das Handwerk GmbH + Co.',   "aktive Stuttgarter", 'ABEX Dachdecker Handwerks-GmbH',
'Academie für Kunst und Handwerk e.V.', 'AHA Agentur fürs Handwerk GmbH']


error = []
for company in companylist:
    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("searchPhrase0")
    inputElement.clear()
    inputElement.send_keys(company)
    inputElement.submit() 

    soup = BS(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

    link = soup.find('span',{'class':'company--name'})
    a_link = link.find('a')['href']

    response = requests.get('https://www.firmenwissen.de' + a_link + '?showEmail=true', headers=headers)
    alpha_soup = BS(response.text, 'html.parser')


    try:
        phone = alpha_soup.find('span', {'class':'yp_phoneNumber'}).text.strip()
    except:
        phone = ''

    try:
        email = alpha_soup.find('span', {'class':'yp_email'}).text.strip()
    except:
        email = ''

    try:
        website = alpha_soup.find('span', {'class':'yp_website'}).text.strip()
    except:
        webiste = ''

    try:
        contact = soup.find('div', {'class':'company--info'})
        address = contact.find_all('p')[-1].text.strip()
    except:
        print ('Could not locate %s company info' %(company))
        error.append(company)

    print('%s\n%s\n%s\n%s\n' %(address, phone, email, website))
```

Comment: thank you very much. Could you please give me one more suggestion. I want to use this website, url = 'https://www.firmenwissen.de/index.html', to search different company. Like I have company list in the code you saw. Now how can I use this website to search? Could you please kindly help.

Comment: I’ll have a look when I get a chance.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much.

Comment: You’re still just trying to search contact info, correct?

Comment: hi did you got a chance to look

Comment: Actually just sat down to look now.

Comment: Yes it's working perfectly. One question this company name, **AHA Agentur fürs Handwerk GmbH**, and search on that website and if you click first link it will take you to next page where you will find some more information like email address and telephone. can you please do that.

Comment: check update above. not perfect, so you'll have to tinker around a bit, but should get you going

Comment: Thank you billion times. It's working as I want to. Thank you. One last question, could you please give me some suggestion, I want to learn more about selenium, beautifulsoup, where I can learn all these. One more thing If I want to chat with you how can i do that? is it possible to chat with you. Please kindly reply. I want to vote your answer is best and perfect what should i do?

Comment: We can always chat by email jason.schvach@gmail.com Sometimes I'm on Discord, but not oftern. honestly, the best way to learn Selenium and BeautifulSoup is just practice playing with it and using it. I'm certainly not an expert, and am still learning, but I basically just try to ask myself, what do I want to do, and then just google it. I can usually find an answer on SO or a youtube tutorial. To accept the answer, there should be a little "check mark"  you can click on next to the Answer. This means you accept the answer to your question.